# How I can use "Search within" via GScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In GDrive there is the feature: Search within ......". How can I implement this function in GScript? My goal is to use this function to count the number of all files and directories.

[image]

Does anyone have a simple script example for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `q` parameter with the value `'A_FOLDER_ID' in parents` of [Drive API files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files) is the documentation for the syntax the `q` parameter accepts.

And [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_folders) is a sample implementation in Apps Scripts for listing folders using the `q` parameter.